# Django and chartjs using json (doesn't show chart)

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax, chart.js

I'm trying to display a chart in Django with data from database using JSON. When I go to `/distancechart` I see my data printed. But when it comes to chart I get blank screen, nothing shows. I was using some tutorials from internet and I have no idea what is wrong here...

views.py fragment

```
def distancechart(request):
    labels = []
    data = []

    queryset = Distance.objects.values('day', 'distance')
    for entry in queryset:
        labels.append(entry['day'])
        data.append(entry['distance'])
    return JsonResponse(data={
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
    })
```

distance.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}

<canvas id="distancechart" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
    $.get('{% url "distancechart" %}', function(data) {
        var ctx = $("#distancechart").get(0).getContext("2d");
        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: data.labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Distance',
                    data: data.data,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    
    });

</script>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Any javascript errors in the console? I've just had a look at a chart that loads data via ajax, and it's basically the same as what you've got here.

Comment: yes, it was because I had slim version of jQuery imported and ajax wasn't there